# Is a limit of profinite spaces profinite?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, limits-colimits

Here is the statement of [Lemma 5.22.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0ET8) in the Stacks Project:

**Lemma.** A cofiltered limit of profinite spaces is profinite.

And here is the proof:

*Proof.* Let us use the characterization of profinite spaces in Lemma 5.22.2. By Lemma 5.14.1 the limit exists. By Theorem 5.14.4 the limit is quasi-compact. A cofiltered limit of totally disconnected spaces is totally disconnected (details omitted). A cofiltered limit of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff (details omitted). This finishes the proof.

If we remove the word "cofiltered" we get:

**Lemma.** A limit of profinite spaces is profinite.

And here is the proof:

*Proof.* Let us use the characterization of profinite spaces in Lemma 5.22.2. By Lemma 5.14.1 the limit exists. By Theorem 5.14.4 the limit is quasi-compact. A limit of totally disconnected spaces is totally disconnected (details omitted). A limit of Hausdorff spaces is Hausdorff (details omitted). This finishes the proof.

I don't see what's wrong with this second version.

What am I missing?

Comment: @freakish - The notions of limit and colimit in the Stacks Project are defined here https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/002D

Comment: @freakish Here "limit" would be "inverse limit" rather than "direct limit".

Comment: @ArnaudD. Oh, wait a minute, so "cofiltered limit" doesn't mean "colimit". This is soo confusing.

Comment: This isn't really even a proof sketch. Tychonoff's theorem 5.14.4 says that a *product* of quasicompact spaces is quasicompact. A limit is a subspace of a product, and of course subspaces of quasicompact spaces are generally not quasicompact. So more has to be said for the compactness of a cofiltered limit, more which presumably doesn't work for equalizers.

Comment: Oops, actually profinite spaces are closed under arbitrary limits! This is because this is true of compact Hausdorff spaces, since the latter are reflective in spaces, and profinite spaces are furthermore reflective in compact Hausdorff spaces, according to this paper, which contains a proof but no original reference: https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.5963

Comment: @KevinCarlson - Thanks! Let's focus on quasi-compactness. It seems to me that a limit of quasi-compact spaces is a *closed* subspace of a product of quasi-compact spaces, and that closed subspaces of quasi-compact spaces are quasi-compact. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Mm, let's see, putting on the point-set topology hat, I think you need Hausdorff here. To know that a regular monomorphism is a closed inclusion, you need $\{f(x)=g(x)\}$ to be closed, which is the inverse image of the diagonal under $(f,g)$. But with that change, I buy it-use compactness and Hausdorffness simultaneously. (or in the French terminology, just compactness :) )

Comment: @KevinCarlson - Yes, you're right! I overlooked the fact that Hausdorffness is needed to show that our equalizer is closed. I completely agree with your comment! Your clarification was very useful to me!

Comment: @KevinCarlson - I'd be most grateful if you upgraded your comment to an answer. (I think it would be nice to have a post with a complete proof of the fact that limits of profinite spaces are profinite.)

Comment: @KevinCarlson [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008620404444) also mentions the reflection of profinite spaces in compact Hausdorff spaces (in section 7), and gives a reference to Bourbaki's *General Topology*, Ch 2, § 4, No 4, Prop 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kevin Carlson explained in a comment, the answer is Yes.

More precisely, say that a space is *compact* if it is quasi-compact and Hausdorff. Then the Stacks Project text can be amended as follows:

**Lemma.** A limit of profinite spaces is profinite.

*Proof.* Let us use the characterization of profinite spaces in Lemma 5.22.2. By Lemma 5.14.1 the limit exists. By Theorem 5.14.4 the limit is compact. A limit of totally disconnected spaces is totally disconnected (details omitted). This finishes the proof.

The key point is that the equalizer of a double arrow $X\rightrightarrows Y$ is closed if $Y$ is Hausdorff (because it is the inverse image of the diagonal under the obvious map $X\to Y\times Y$, and the diagonal is closed since $Y$ is Hausdorff).

(I confess with shame that, when I wrote the question, I thought that equalizers were *always* closed. I'm sure I knew that this was not so when I leaned general topology, but I forgot it. I know it's silly...)